# Round timestamp to microsecond - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, rounding

I can't seem to find this but I'm sure it's somewhere on SO. I'm hoping to round timestamps to a single microsecond. Other rounding frequencies are working but when I try to round the following to a single decimal place it's not working.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time' : ['2019-08-02 09:50:10.040','2019-08-02 09:50:10.080','2019-08-02 09:50:10.170','2019-08-02 09:50:10.180'],                  
        })

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

df["time"] = df.time.dt.round("1L")
```

intended output:

```
                     time
0 2019-08-02 09:50:10.0
1 2019-08-02 09:50:10.1
2 2019-08-02 09:50:10.2
3 2019-08-02 09:50:10.2
```

Comment: the title is misleading - it seems you want to round to the tenth of a second, not microsecond (millionth of a second)

Comment: @MrFuppes indeed, I removed my comment, just wanted to help - I've never coded in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might have overlooked combining [offset aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases).

Rounding by `100L` should give the right answer in your case. `100L` would round using the arbitration of 100 milliseconds (or 0.1 seconds), exactly what you need in this case. You were using `1L`, which was already the default value in the dataframe.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time' : ['2019-08-02 09:50:10.040','2019-08-02 09:50:10.080','2019-08-02 09:50:10.170','2019-08-02 09:50:10.180'],                  
        })

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

df['time'] = df.time.dt.round('100L')
```

The output is:

```
0   2019-08-02 09:50:10.000
1   2019-08-02 09:50:10.100
2   2019-08-02 09:50:10.200
3   2019-08-02 09:50:10.200
```

The extra zeroes can't be truncated, but computation-wise, you will be getting the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is:

```py
df["time"] = df.time.dt.round("100ms")
```

Output

```
                     time
0 2019-08-02 09:50:10.000
1 2019-08-02 09:50:10.100
2 2019-08-02 09:50:10.200
3 2019-08-02 09:50:10.200
```

---

Here are all valid strings:

```
    'A': 'A-DEC',
    'AS': 'AS-JAN',
    'BA': 'BA-DEC',
    'BAS': 'BAS-JAN',
    'BY': 'BA-DEC',
    'BYS': 'BAS-JAN',
    'Min': 'T',
    'Q': 'Q-DEC',
    'W': 'W-SUN',
    'Y': 'A-DEC',
    'YS': 'AS-JAN',
    'min': 'T',
    'ms': 'L',
    'ns': 'N',
    'us': 'U',
```